# PopupWindow doesn't show

Tags: android, popupwindow, popupmenu

I have a PopupWindow in my app.
That is how I initialize it:

```
final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));
hashTagsWindow = new PopupWindow(frameLayout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
hashTagsWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
```

And that is how I try to show it:

```
  hashTagsWindow.showAsDropDown(binding.hash, 20, 20);
```

But my PopupWindow doesn't display itself.

What I already tried to solve a problem?:

- Wrap `.showAsDropDown(...)`to the `.post(Runnable)` and `.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`
- All the methods of PopupWindow which should show it.
- `PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropdown(...)` method.

All this things didn't help me.

Meanwhile a PopupMenu class correctly displays in the same context. But I need PopupWindow.

What should I do to show PopupWindow?

Comment: did you call .show() cause i don't see it there

Comment: PopupWindow has no .show() method

Comment: Sorry i got confused with ListPopupWindow.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this method, May help you.

```
private void showPopupWindow(View view){

    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mView=mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_layout, null);

    mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(mView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    // mPopupWindow=new PopupWindow(mView,,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mPopupWindow.setContentView(mView);

    Button mBtnCancel=(Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    mBtnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, 0, 0, Gravity.LEFT);

    mPopupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            Drawable d = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE);
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you gave a bit of explanation about what the code does?